# Searching in files and folder is extremely slow in Python

Tags: python, csv

i'll try to explain what i want to achieve with my code:

1. i open a csv file
2. i pick up every element of the first row and search for this string in every file in every subdirectory starting from rootdir.

with the design showed below, it is extremely slow even with 2 directories and one file in each directory.
It takes approximately 1 second for each entry on the main file. i've got 400000 records on that file...

```
import csv
import os

rootdir = 'C:\Users\ST\Desktop\Sample'
f = open('C:\Users\ST\Desktop\inputIds.csv')
f.readline()
snipscsv_f=csv.reader(f, delimiter='    ')
for row in snipscsv_f:
    print 'processing another ID'
    for subdir, dir, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        print 'processing another folder'
        for file in files:
            print 'processing another file'
            if 'csv' in file: #i want only csv files to be processed
                ft = open(os.path.join(subdir, file))
                for ftrow in ft:
                    if row[0] in ftrow:
                        print row[0]
                ft.close()
```

Comment: I mean. This is going to be really really really slow because of the sheer volume of files you're looking through. Can you provide some context onto what your end goal is here because there is likely a way to improve your setup substantially.

Comment: Holy wow. You are searching for, and reading, all the CSV files once for each line of your ID file. Instead, read your input ID file once, store the IDs in a variable, and read each CSV file once and check whether any of the IDs are in each line. Also, once you have found a match, `break` out of the loop so you don't read the rest of the file. If the files you're searching are small enough, you may also get some speedup by reading them into memory instead of line by line.

Comment: can you post some sample lines for your id file and other files？

Comment: `cut -d, -f1 inputIds.csv > Ids.txt` then `grep -f Ids.txt -r *.csv`  ?  (Edit, oh right, Windows. http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ has Win32 builds of GNU utils for cut and grep, if you want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you have a large CSV file but it is still MUCH quicker to read it all and compare against, rather than performing the os walk for every entry.

Also, not sure that python is the best tool for this. You may find shell scripts (for windows, Powershell is the only decent tool) much faster for this kind of task. Anyway, you added python tags so...

```
import csv
import fnmatch
import os

# load the csv with entries
with open('file_with_entries.csv','r') as f:
    readr = csv.reader(f)
    data = []
    for row in readr:
        data.extend(row)

# find csv files
rootdir = os.getcwd() # could be anywhere
matches = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.csv'):
        matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

# find occurences of entry in each file
for eachcsv in matches:
    with open(eachcsv, 'r') as f:
        text = f.read()
        for entry in data:
            if entry in text:
                print("found %s in %s" % (entry,eachcsv))
```

Not sure how critical it is that you *only* read the first row of the entries file, it would be reasonably easier to amend to the code to do just that.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the input. The only problem is that it is possible that there is more than 1 match on each file and i need to keep track of all of them.